# Schedule a QPython script to run daily (on android device)

Tags: android, qpython

I would like to know what is the best way I could schedule a script to run daily on my android device, using the `QPython` app.

**What are your suggestions?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Tasker" and QPython plugin for tasker to automate the script.

Here is the link:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qpython.tasker2&hl=en